# How do I make a class extending another extended class work with generic collections?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

In our current codebase, we have the following data structure to communicate between our service layer and our frontend layer:

```
public class BaseView {
    private Integer id;
    // Other common attributes and getters/setters;
}

public class BarView extends BaseView {
    private String name;
    private String Description;
    // Other attributes for this object and getters/setters;
}
```

We also have a number of double extended classes:

```
public class BazView extends BaseView {
    // name, description, other common attributes;
}

public class BazTypeAView extends BazView {
    // attributes specific to Type A Baz;
}

public class BazTypeBView extends BazView {
    // attributes specific to Type B Baz;
}
```

In our service layer, we have service methods implementing a BaseService: a `BarService`, a `BazService`, a `BazTypeAService`, a `BazTypeBService` and other with a similar naming scheme which all have methods returning either the class they're responsible for, or a `List<class they are responsible for>`. In turn, each of these methods calls a method from the BaseService with signature `GetObjects(Class Viewtype, Class BeanType, Criteria)`, with the criteria based on parameters passed into the specific method method. the Beans are between the Service Layer and the Data Access Layer and not really relevant to this.

An example of the scheme:

```
public interface BaseService {
    public BaseView getObject(Class viewType, class beanType, Integer id);

    public List<BaseView> getObjects(Class viewType, class beanType, Criteria criteria);
}

public class BaseServiceImpl implements BaseService {
    protected BaseView getObject(Class viewType, class beanType, Integer id){
        BaseBean bean = (BaseBean) DataService.getobject (beanType, id);
        BaseView view = ViewGenerator.createEmptyView(viewType);
        copyAttributes(bean, view);
        return view;
    }

    protected List<BaseView> getObject(Class viewType, class beanType, Criteria criteria){
        List<BaseBean> bean = (List<BaseBean>) DataService.getobject (beanType, Criteria);
        List<BaseView> view = new ArrayList<BaseView>();
        copyAttributes(bean, view);
        return view;
    }
}

public interface BarService extends BaseService {
    public BarView getBar(Integer id);

    public List<BarView> getBars(BarView barView);
}

public class BarServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl implements BarService {
    public BarView getBar(Integer id){
       BarView bar = getObject(BarView.class, BarBean.class, id);
       return bar;
    }

    public List<BarView> getBars(BarView barView){
       Criteria criteria = getCriteriaFromBarView(barView);
       List<BarView> bars = getObjects(BarView.class, BarBean.class, criteria);
       return bars;
    }
}
```

The above is roughly how the system works. The methods to create a Bar, get a list of Bars, update a Bar and delete a Bar all are effectively the same as the above.

the problem is that getObject returns a raw List, leading to a lot of Eclipse warnings and code that's harder to read. over 2/3 of our warnings for this project are about raw type usage, and though our code still compiles and works as it should, it's A LOT of messages.

If we didn't have the second kind of View which extends an extended class, we could just do `List<? extends Fooview>`, but that gives errors for the classes extending BazView. Is there a way to make generic types work here when you have both ? extends Baseview and ? extends X extends Baseview?

Comment: @AxelH the problem is that we sometimes have methods in our Services that return a different view. For example, BarService might have a method GetConnectedBazTypeAs() which returns a list of type BazTypeA.

Comment: Off course, but for each Service, you will need to put set the generic type to the correct type of View.

Comment: Here I explain a bit more in the answer

Answer (score 2):

My answer does not differ much from the others, except that I guess your BaseService is an interface:

> In our service layer, we have service methods **implementing** a BaseService

I would define the interface like that(**EDIT**):

```
public interface BaseService<T extends FooView>{
    T getObject(Class<T> viewType, Class<? extends FooBean> beanType, Integer id);    
    List<T> getAllObjects(Class<T> viewType, Class<? extends FooBean> beanType);
}
```

(**ADDED**)
Implementing that interface in an abstract class requires that all depending services use generics as well:

```
public abstract class BaseServiceImpl<T extends FooView> implements BaseService<T>{
    @Override
    public T getObject(Class<T> viewType, Class<? extends FooBean> beanType, Integer id){
        FooBean bean = DataService.getObject(beanType, id);
        T view = ViewGenerator.createEmptyView(viewType);
        copyAttributes(bean, view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> getAllObjects(Class<T> viewType, Class<? extends FooBean> beanType){
        List<? extends FooBean> beanList = DataService.getAllObjects(beanType);

        return beanList.stream().map(bean -> {
            T view = ViewGenerator.createEmptyView(viewType);
            copyAttributes(bean, view);
            return view;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private void copyAttributes(FooBean bean, T view){}
}
```

(**EDIT**)
The implementation of all your services should be straight forward then:

```
public class BarServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl<BarView> implements BarService{

    @Override
    public BarView getBar(Integer id){
        return getObject(BarView.class, BarBean.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<BarView> getAllBars(){
        return getAllObjects(BarView.class, BarBean.class);
    }
}

public class BazServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl<BazView> implements BazService{
    @Override
    public BazView getBaz(Integer id){
        return getObject(BazView.class, BazBean.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<BazView> getAllBazs(){
        return getAllObjects(BazView.class, BazBean.class);
    }
}

public class BazTypeAServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl<BazTypeAView> implements BazTypeAService{
    @Override
    public BazTypeAView getBazTypeA(Integer id){
        return getObject(BazTypeAView.class, BazTypeABean.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<BazTypeAView> getAllBazTypeAs(){
        return getAllObjects(BazTypeAView.class, BazTypeABean.class);
    }
}
```

At least in my main method there are no warning because everything is cleanly typed:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BarService barService = new BarServiceImpl();
        BarView barView = barService.getBar(111);
        List<BarView> barViewList = barService.getAllBars();

        BazService bazService = new BazServiceImpl();
        BazView bazView = bazService.getBaz(222);
        List<BazView> bazViewList = bazService.getAllBazs();

        BazTypeAService bazTypeAService = new BazTypeAServiceImpl();
        BazTypeAView bazTypeAView = bazTypeAService.getBazTypeA(333);
        List<BazTypeAView> bazTypeAViewList bazTypeAService.getAllBazTypeAs();
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**

Replacing the interface with an abstract class(if possible) would reduce the code again because both of the sample methods could be implemented in the abstract class. The main method wouldn't need to change at all.

**EDIT**

You need to use generics also at that level where you create your objects. Otherwise you need a lot of casting and you get those ugly warnings with your lists. I updated my sample for you.

**EDIT2**

I already mentioned it before that your  **DataService** and your **ViewGenerator** need to use generics too. This is how I would implement the method bodies:

```
public class DataService    {
    public static <T extends FooBean> T getObject(Class<T> beanType, Integer id){return null;}    
    public static <T extends FooBean> List<T> getAllObjects(Class<T> beanType){return null;}
}

public class ViewGenerator    {
    public static <T> T createEmptyView(Class<T> viewType){return null;}
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question with a clearer explanation of my service layer. How would I apply your solution to my situation?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, what you need is to make your `BaseService` get a generic type that will be used in the `getObject` method:

BaseService class:

```
public class <T extends FooView> BaseService<T> {
  public T getObject() { 
   ...
  }
}
```

and in the specific services:

```
public class BazTypeAService extends BaseService<BazTypeAView> {
  ...
}
```

Comment: How would I apply your solution to my situation (updated in the question)?

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer to use the code styling, I will delete it if I didn't not understand well.

Try to use a generic type like this :

```
public abstract class BarService<T extends FooView>{
    List<T> list;
    ...

    public List<T> getList(){ return list;}
}

public class BazService extends BarService<BazView>{
    ...
}

public class BazTypeBService extends BarService<BazTypeBView>{
    ...
}

...
```

Here,

```
BazService.getList() will return a List<BazView> instance
BazTypeBService .getList() will return a List<BazTypeBView> instance
```

Comment: I've given a rudimentary example of how our servicelayer roughly works in the question, because I wasn't quite clear on how it worked. I'm not quite sure how to apply your example to my scenario.

Comment: You speak of list but don't have this on you example, your example is not clear, what is the Base*** class/interface.

Comment: Updated to clarify what the Base view is and how it works for getting a list of Views.

Comment: @Nzall You need to change your methods to getObject, getList like I did, having a getFoo, getBar, get*** won't help you in generic classes.